# Send iframe app invites

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to send invites to people to from my iframe tab application using the FB.ui method. My code sends the dialogue perfectly, and the users does receive the app request, however, when clicking on the request they get a "An error occurred with RCS Let's make it possible. Please try again later." error.

This application can ONLY run through the facebook iframe tab, so, I want the users to go to the tab location, not the application page.

Any ideas would be greatly welcome!

The code:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
                        message: 'Play RCS Let\'s make it happen game!'
                    }, function(data) {
                        $("#sendToFriends").fadeOut();
                        $("#didyouknow").fadeIn();
                        console.log(data);
                    });
```

Comment: How does the error occur? Is it one of the FB dialog box type errors? Or is this an error generated by your script?

Comment: Once you click on the notification, the message is provided by FB on the next screen :)

Comment: The only reason I have heard in the past for errors like these is due to `request_ids` not marrying up properly. Are you handling the request_ids with a callback URI for clicked requests?

Comment: It appears that when someone sends me the invite, and me being the admin, I see the application, but when the invite is sent to other people they get the error.

Comment: Sounds like your app has Sandbox mode enabled in your app settings.

Comment: I double checked and it's definately not in Sandbox mode. I also added the url to the "apps of facebook" of my app. Not sure if this is worth moentioning, but my app does not have a http:// nor a www., it literally just runs off a https:// protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

The solution is in fact not a code issue, but you should go under your Facebook Developers app settings > Auth Dialog and ensure that you have Authenticated Referrals turned off.